# How do I get Volume data on Expert adviser?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

How do I get Volume data on Expert Adviser? (not Indicator)

I know that way to get Volume on Indicator.
So I want to bring Volume data to Expert Adviser.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long value = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, 0); //mt4

long value = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, 0); 
long iVolume(const string symbol,const ENUM_TIMEFRAMES tf, const int shift){
   long timeseries[1];
   if(CopyTickVolume(symbol,tf,shift,1,timeseries)==1)
      return timeseries[0];
   return -1;
}  // mt5, CopyRealVolume is same
```

Comment: Which value (RealVolume or TickVolume) contains Volume[] of MetaTrader4?  I want to get value as same as Volume[] on MT4.

Comment: CopyTickVolume is what you need